# System.ArgumentException in app when accepting appointment

Tags: c#, uwp, appointment, argumentexception

When accepting an appointment, an ArgumentException is thrown in the calling UWP C#/XAML app. Canceling the appointment seems to work fine, though.

I've trimmed the impacted code to:

```cs
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(async () =>
        {
            var appt = new Appointment();
            var rect = new Rect(new Point(Window.Current.Bounds.Width / 2, Window.Current.Bounds.Height / 2), new Size());
            string id = await AppointmentManager.ShowAddAppointmentAsync(appt, rect, Placement.Default);
            Debug.WriteLine(id);
        });
    });
}

/* ArgumentException
HResult=-2147024809
Message=Value does not fall within the expected range.
Source=mscorlib
StackTrace:
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at eovimcd_mobile_windows.MainPage.<>c.<<Button_Click>b__4_1>d.MoveNext()
*/
```

The following line triggers the launch of the calendar app for the user to confirm adding the appointment:

```
string id = await AppointmentManager.ShowAddAppointmentAsync(appt, rect, Placement.Default);
```

The ArgumentException is raised on that line when accepting the appointment, canceling resumes the execution as expected.

I'm aware that removing the Task and dispatch on UI thread works perfectly. The app is built in a way that the trigger for the appointment creation is received from an embedded web view, followed by a task run, and finally forcing the execution of the appointment creation on the UI thread.

Comment: If I were a betting man, I would say that your new Rect is taking in a negative number. But it's hard to say without seeing values

Comment: I'll edit my question and stress the fact that the exception is thrown when the user accepts the appointment. Canceling works fine, the execution resumes.

Comment: From your trace... it looks like `eovimcd_mobile_windows.MainPage.<>c.<<Button_Click>b__4_1>d.MoveNext()` is trying to move outside the bounds of its collection.

You can use `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();` to force a break point in your code, that'll at least let you step through and see.